# About Lines and Planes in Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra

The set of linear combinations $cX$ is said to span a line. How can I see that there's correspondence between $cX$ and the equation of a line $ax + by = 0$? Besides, the aforementioned equation looks very much like the set of all linear combinations $ax + ay$ that is said to span a plane.

Please, elaborate.

Comment: This is only the case for dimension $2$.

Comment: Don't get confused by the superficial similarity between $ax+by=0$ which is an equation, whose solutions form a line, and the span of two vectors, which typically forms a plane.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $a$ and $b$ are both zero then the set of solutions to the equation $ax+by=0$ is all of $\mathbb{R}^2$.  Otherwise the set of solutions is $\{c\cdot(b,-a): c\in \mathbb{R}\}$, which is the span of $X=(b,-a)$, a nonzero vector in $\mathbb{R}^2$.